# List all TLS Ciphers the Client supports in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, tls1.2

I have a simple Nodejs server running with the following code:

```js
const https = require("http2");
const fs = require("fs");

const PORT = 443;

let server = https.createSecureServer({
    allowHTTP1: true,
    key:  fs.readFileSync("./key.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./cert.pem")
});

server.on("error", console.log);

server.on("request", (request, response) => {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end("Hello, World", "utf-8");
});
```

I know that I can get the cipher used for the current connection using `request.socket.getCipher()`.

How do I get a list of **all** the Ciphers that the client sends in the `ClientHello` message?
I would prefer a Nodejs solution, without using external tools like `tshark` or `tcpdump`.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `request.socket.getSharedSigalgs()`

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for.